# css place text on centered image in a div

Tags: css

I need to place text(absolute position) on centered placing image in a div.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="col-md-12 profile-settings">
     <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 notifications">              
        <a href="#"><img src="../img/profile/notifications.png" alt="" class="normal"><span class="notification-count"><span>04</span></span></a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.profile-settngs li img
{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
 ul li.notifications a
{
  position: relative;
}    
 .notification-count
{
  border-radius: 60%;
  left: 57px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 46px;
  width: 18px;
}
```

But it is working fine for 1280x960 resolution. but other resolutions, the text got changing the position.
If i remove margin-left and margin-right(for center the image) it is working fine.

Comment: will you notification count will go to 3 digits if not you can use this http://jsfiddle.net/ugee6t39/1/

Comment: thanks Vitorino, its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place span text to image set position relative to a and position absolute to span. Try like this-

```
    <head>
<style>
.profile-settngs li img{
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;

}
 ul li.notifications a{
   position: relative;
}

 .notification-count{
    border-radius: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: -9px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}


</style>
</head>
<ul class="col-md-12 profile-settings">
            <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 notifications">              
              <a href="#"><img src="img/1.png" alt="" class="normal"><span class="notification-count"><span>04</span></span></a>
            </li>
</ul>
```